# How to split document by page in Azure AI Search?

Tags: azure, azure-cognitive-search, azure-ai-search

As title.

I have several PDFs stored in Azure blob and entered Azure AI Search and using `SplitSkill`.

However, even if `textSplitMod` is set to pages, I still can't split document by pages.

The skillset JSON code is as follows:

```
{
      "@odata.type": "#Microsoft.Skills.Text.SplitSkill",
      "name": "#2",
      "description": "Split skill to chunk documents",
      "context": "/document",
      "defaultLanguageCode": "en",
      "textSplitMode": "pages",
      "maximumPageLength": 2000,
      "pageOverlapLength": 500,
      "maximumPagesToTake": 0,
      "inputs": [
        {
          "name": "text",
          "source": "/document/mergedText"
        }
      ],
      "outputs": [
        {
          "name": "textItems",
          "targetName": "pages"
        }
```

How can I achieve the goal of splitting according to page numbers?

Because I want the search output to show the answer along with the corresponding page number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The text split skill breaks documents into chunks, which are used for further processing by other cognitive skills.

Below, you can see that I have added the field mappings of the output of the text split skill to the index. Even though all pages are indexed at the same source document, when using it in other cognitive skills by providing input like `/document/mypages/*`, it processes each page.

[image]

Below is the sample I used for language detection skill on each page.

```json
{
  "@odata.context": "https://jgsai.search.windows.net/$metadata#skillsets/$entity",
  "@odata.etag": "\"0x8DC37696B99977C\"",
  "name": "skillset1709010100983",
  "description": "",
  "skills": [
    {
      "@odata.type": "#Microsoft.Skills.Text.SplitSkill",
      "name": "#1",
      "description": null,
      "context": "/document",
      "defaultLanguageCode": "en",
      "textSplitMode": "pages",
      "maximumPageLength": 1000,
      "pageOverlapLength": 0,
      "maximumPagesToTake": 0,
      "inputs": [
        {
          "name": "text",
          "source": "/document/content"
        },
        {
          "name": "languageCode",
          "source": "/document/language"
        }
      ],
      "outputs": [
        {
          "name": "textItems",
          "targetName": "mypages"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "@odata.type": "#Microsoft.Skills.Text.LanguageDetectionSkill",
      "name": "#2",
      "description": "",
      "context": "/document/mypages/*",
      "defaultCountryHint": "in",
      "modelVersion": "latest",
      "inputs": [
        {
          "name": "text",
          "source": "/document/mypages/*"
        }
      ],
      "outputs": [
        {
          "name": "languageCode",
          "targetName": "languageCode"
        },
        {
          "name": "languageName",
          "targetName": "languageName"
        },
        {
          "name": "score",
          "targetName": "score"
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "cognitiveServices": {
    "@odata.type": "#Microsoft.Azure.Search.DefaultCognitiveServices",
    "description": null
  },
  "knowledgeStore": null,
  "indexProjections": null,
  "encryptionKey": null
}
```

However, what you are asking about getting pages in the index cannot be done. You can either use the output of the text split skill, or refer to the [knowledge store](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/knowledge-store-create-rest) to create each of the pages and create a new separate index with those pages.

Comment: How can I display "page 1 of 6" like you do, because my pages only have text?

Comment: Actually it is the content of page. Not page 1. The split gives all pages

Comment: I understand what you mean, thank you for your answer

Answer (score 0):

If you only have PDFs, you can use the [generateNormalizedImagePerPage feature in addition to OCR](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/search/cognitive-search-concept-image-scenarios#configure-indexers-for-image-processing) to extract your text, and then you will also have a pageNumber available that you can map to the index. If you want each page to be its own document in the index, you can do so by using the [new preview index projections feature](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/search/index-projections-concept-intro?tabs=kstore-rest).

Your indexer definition would look something like this:

```
{
    "name": "indexerName",
    "targetIndexName": "indexName",
    "skillsetName": "skillsetName",
    "dataSourceName": "dataSourceName",
    "parameters": {
        "configuration": {
            "imageAction": "generateNormalizedImagePerPage"
        }
    },
    "fieldMappings": [],
    "outputFieldMappings": []
}
```

And your skillset definition will look something like this:

```
{
    "skills": [
        {
            "description": "Extracts text (plain and structured) from image.",
            "@odata.type": "#Microsoft.Skills.Vision.OcrSkill",
            "context": "/document/normalized_images/*",
            "inputs": [
                {
                    "name": "image",
                    "source": "/document/normalized_images/*"
                }
            ],
            "outputs": [
                {
                    "name": "text",
                    "targetName": "text"
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
    "cognitiveServices": {
        "@odata.type": "#Microsoft.Azure.Search.CognitiveServicesByKey",
        "description": "CognitiveServices account",
        "key": "{{cognitiveServicesKey}}"
    },
    "indexProjections": {
        "selectors": [
            {
                "targetIndexName": "indexName",
                "parentKeyFieldName": "ParentKey",
                "sourceContext": "/document/normalized_images/*",
                "mappings": [
                    {
                        "name": "pageText",
                        "source": "/document/normalized_images/*/text"
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "pageNumber",
                        "source": "/document/normalized_images/*/pageNumber"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ],
        "parameters": {
            "projectionMode": "skipIndexingParentDocuments"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your advice. I happened to be trying this method and ran into difficulties.

Comment: I use "Import and vectorize data" to create the index, and "/document/normalized_images/*/pageNumber" to create the source pdf page number corresponding to the chunk text, but what I actually get is all page numbers.